# Why Data Factory can access to my secured Blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I can't find the answer to this question :

Why can Data Factory / Synapse access to my blob data **without Private Endpoint**?
Does the System-Assign Managed Identity allow this?
Can I be sure that the traffic is routing safely?

Here you can see the network configuration

[image]

and Private endpoint connections

[image]

Here is the Dataset configuration

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate on the error/issue while implementing the above procedure regarding Blob storage ?

Comment: I have no error. As you can see I have access to my blob with the Default IntegrationRuntime without configuring any Private Link or Endpoints. Is it normal ?